# How to select the last row details of a column name in php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello this is  what I am trying

**PHP Code :**

```
$ret=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT Last *  
                       FROM commission
                       WHERE admin_phone = '$userphone'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
```

I am trying to fetch last details of a table which have a column name is admin_phone,

Comment: Can you post the full table definition?

Comment: use desc on id and limit 1

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you print the $row and see?

Comment: result is saying mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result on, line ....... you have a sql syntax error

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I would think the answer would be yes as that is syntactically incorrect SQL

Comment: MySQL does not support a `LAST` operator.  Maybe you're thinking of something like `TOP` in SQL Server?  MySQL has a `LIMIT` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM commission
WHERE admin_phone = 'somenum'
ORDER BY some_col DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

To make this approach work, you would need to have a column `some_col` which can be used to provide the ordering.  Actually, without a column to provide ordering, your question does not make much sense.

Also: You should learn about using prepared statements in PHP.  That isn't really the focus of your question, which is mostly on the MySQL side, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: some_col is primary key ?

Comment: `some_col` is _any_ column which can provide the ordering you want.  By which column(s) do you determine that a given record is "last?"  If you can answer that, then you're close to what you want.

Comment: you can use ```SELECT top(1) *
FROM commission
WHERE admin_phone = 'somenum'
ORDER BY some_col DESC```

Comment: @Tim oky I will accept it as my answer after 2 minuts because it is saying that I can accept this answer in 2 mins